# HTML recognize json HTML values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a json as an hml value that I would like to present an html div, but the value is displayed as text. There is an option for html to recognize my json html tags

Ex:

```
{
"title": "Ajuste Relatório de Entidades",
"description": "<p>Boa Tarde Prezados ,</p><p><span style=\"font-size: 1rem;\">Ao tentarmos extrair o “relatório de entidades” conta Martins o sistema nos traz apenas algumas entidades (em anexo), sendo que temos cadastradas mais de 400 destinatários , ou seja , no relatório deveria conter todas as entidades cadastradas.</span><br></p><p><span style=\"font-size: 1rem;\">Módulo : Relatórios -&gt; Relatórios Personalizados – 14 – Relatório de entidades&nbsp;</span></p><p><img
```

I would like to take the json description property and play it in a div

Comment: HTML has no way to recognise anything related to JSON at all. You've tagged this [tag:javascript], if you are using JS to read the JSON and generate the HTML from it, then that's where the problem lies but you need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use innerHTML = your json value

Here is an example:

```js
    const data = {
      title: "Ajuste Relatório de Entidades",
      description: `<p style="font-weight:bold">Boa Tarde Prezados </p>`
    };
    
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data.title;
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = data.description;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
</body>
</html>
```